# ¿Existe una palabra para designar a los homófonos formados por más de una palabra?

Tags: solicitud-de-término, lingüística, rima

[**Homófono**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=KbZUpzR) es (negrita mía)

> 1. adj. *Ling*. Dicho de **una palabra**: Que suena igual que otra, pero que tiene distinto significado y puede tener distinta grafía. U. t. c. s. m. *Aunque se distinguen ortográficamente, tubo y tuvo son homófonos.*

¿Existe un término análogo para los casos en los que el mismo sonido está formado por más de una palabra? Por ejemplo: "**helado**" y "**el hado**" suenan igual, pero no se pueden denominar **homófonos** porque "*el hado*" no es una palabra, sino dos.

Comment: No son homófonos: helado y hado. Lo que suena igual no es por homofonía formalmente hablando.

Comment: @Lambie: Creo que eso se indica ya en la pregunta, donde dice en el párrafo final, segunda frase: "... pero no se pueden denominar homófonos ..."

Comment: @Alcor Sí, y lo he repetido de otra manera. ¿ Hay algun inconveniente?

Answer (score 8):

Cuando la coincidencia es intencional se conoce como "calambur":

> [**Calambur**](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calambur)
>
> El calambur es un juego de palabras, basándose en la homonimia, en la paronimia o en la polisemia. Consiste en modificar el significado de una palabra o frase agrupando de distinta forma sus sílabas. Por ejemplo: "plata no es" y "plátano es".

Comment: Pero lo que me interesa también es cuando **no es un juego de palabras** intencionado o no. Por ejemplo al enseñar español a no hispano-parlantes